# SL7 (Fedora) Bluetooth Audio

Tags: audio, fedora, bluetooth, scientific-linux

I have installed Scientific Linux (a variant of Fedora). Ever since I installed it, the connection to Bluetooth speakers has been hit and miss.

I have the Gnome desktop. The Bluetooth device is discovered, ISB394.

If I have audio playing out of the laptop speakers, then attempt to connect with the Bluetooth speaker, the sound goes away for a few seconds, then returns to the laptop speakers. No errors messages. No notifications.

Is there a log I should look in?

The Bluetooth speakers work fine under Windows 7.

I have installed the following packages:
bluez, bluez-alsa, bluez-compat